# TVOS Equivalent to UIActivityViewController

Tags: tvos, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am cross developing an app for TVOS and iOS and Mac. We want to be able to share pictures with some text.

On iOS this is trivial with a UIActivityViewController.
On Mac this is easy with the NSSharingServicePicker.
On TVOS I have no idea how to do this.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @kalpa No. The TVOS version won't have social media integration.